# how are filterCriter.attributes encoded in a CoAP oneM2M request?

Tags: coap, onem2m

In the oneM2M HTTP protocol binding spec (TS-0009) it says:

> Any of the short names listed in table 6.2.2.2-1, with the exception of ‘atr’, may be used in the query-string. The short name ‘atr’ itself is not used. Instead, any of the resource attribute short names as listed in tables 8.2.3-1 to 8.2.3-5 in oneM2M TS-0004 [3] may be used in the query-string in representations of attname=attvalue expressions...

However, there is no mention of how the key/value pairs in `filterCriteria.attribute` are supposed to be encoded in a CoAP request (eg, in TS-0008).

Is this specified somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

"atr", ie. the resource attributes in a query, are part of the *Filter Criteria* (see TS-0004, section 7.3.3.17.9). *Filter Criteria* elements are encoded in the CoAP *uri-query* option (see TS-0008, the last paragraph of section "6.2.2.3 URI Options").

See also [IETF RFC 7252, section 6.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252#section-6.5), which step 8, defines how to encode key/value pairs in the *uri-query* option.